# How to get an actual file from a blob with git2go / libgit2?

Tags: go, libgit2

So this might be due to my ignorance of what git does under the hood, but I'm trying to clone a repo using git2go like you would with running `git clone <repo url>` in bash.  I can clone the repo to get the content of the usual .git/ folder repos have.  Then I am trying to get the actual project files from there.  To do this I get the index of the repo returned from the clone, then I write a tree with that index.  Then I get lost, but here's what I'm currently doing:

```
type Project struct {
    conf      config.Project
    State     string
    ABSPath   string
    Services  map[string]*Service
    creds     *credentials.RawCredentials
    gitCreds  *git.Cred
    clonePath string
    CloneOpts *git.CloneOptions
}

func (p *Project) Unpack(repo *git.Repository) error {
    index, indexErr := repo.Index()
    if indexErr != nil {
        return indexErr
    }
    log.Println(*index)
    oid, writeErr := index.WriteTree()
    if writeErr != nil {
        return writeErr
    }
    blob, blobErr := repo.LookupBlob(oid)
    if blobErr != nil {
        return blobErr
    }
    content := blob.Contents()
    log.Println((string)(content))
    return nil
}
```

Currently, content is empty.  My goal here is to unpack the entire repo.  I believe I need to walk through the working tree in order to do that.  Am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: Are you saying `git.Clone()` isn't writing the files to the workdir? Part of the clone process is the initial checkout, if it's not happening, that's a bug.

Comment: When you called `git.Clone()`, if you didn't include `&CloneOptions{Bare:true}`, then your working directory should be populated. Like @Carlos, if not, that's a bug.

Comment: @matt.s yup, you're right, mind making that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `git.Clone()`, if you don't include `&CloneOptions{Bare:true}`, then your working directory should be populated.